# Excel Export as html fails to show borders in Excel 2016

Tags: javascript, css, export-to-excel

I am exporting html to an Excel `xls` file using JavaScript as in following demo: http://js.do/sun21170/84913.  I have used Google Chrome to run this demo but it should run in Edge or IE or FireFox also.

The problem is that when I open the exported file in `Excel 2016`, it shows without any borders even though there is CSS in the exported html to show borders.

**Question**: Is there a way to show the borders when html file opens in Excel? The same html that opens in Excel, renders with borders in a browser, so the CSS for borders is correct. The demo at http://js.do/sun21170/84913 also shows the html being saved in Excel file.

[image: Html Table with missing Borders]

**HTML saved as xls file**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style> table, td {border:1px solid black} table {border-collapse:collapse}</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Customer</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Product1</td>
            <td>Customer1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Product2</td>
            <td>Customer2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Product3</td>
            <td>Customer3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Product4</td>
            <td>Customer4</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the answer after a lot of research. It seems that Excel 2016 does not like a border thickness of `1px`; anything greater than 1px like 2px or 3px or 4px works. *Why Excel 2016 behaves like this is unclear to me.*

A demo showing this is at following URL: http://js.do/sun21170/84961

Also, if the border thickness is specified in any other units like em or pt or  mm, then a thickness of `1em` or `1mm` or `1pt` or `1mm` or `.5mm` will work.

Even border thickness using pre-defined values like `thin` or `medium` or `thick` works in Excel 2016.

`So, the lesson I have learnt is to never specify border thickness of 1 px when using Excel`.

Following CSS are different styles that worked in Excel 2016 to create a border.

**Border thickness greater than 1px WORKS**

```
var table = "<html><head><style> table, td {border:2px solid black}
            table {border-collapse:collapse}</style></head><body><table><tr>";
```

**Border thickness of 1pt WORKS**

```
var table = "<html><head><style> table, td {border:1pt solid black}
            table {border-collapse:collapse}</style></head><body><table><tr>";
```

**Border thickness of 1mm WORKS**

```
var table = "<html><head><style> table, td {border:1mm solid black}
            table {border-collapse:collapse}</style></head><body><table><tr>";
```

**Border thickness of 1em WORKS**

```
var table = "<html><head><style> table, td {border:1em solid black}
            table {border-collapse:collapse}</style></head><body><table><tr>";
```

**Border thickness of thin WORKS**

```
var table = "<html><head><style> table, td {border:thin solid black}
            table {border-collapse:collapse}</style></head><body><table><tr>";
```

Comment: Great. Works perfectly. I tried to fix Excel year in your answer but small changes aren't allowed in stackoverflow

Comment: Jose, Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected the year part for Excel.

Comment: Hi, I've to show all excel sheet cells bordered. Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the thing is that you have to use:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;"></table>
```

And that's it the **boder** property solves the problem.

Comment: Perfect solution, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding border will not solve the problem fully, because it will only do border around the data, **except the data whole page will still appear as blank**.

So solving it and make excel sheet appear as normal as it appear natively we have to add some **xml attributes** as i have used in below example, use that attributes and it will show the table as it appear in normal excel files.

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Role</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Bob</td>
                <td>Singer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tom </td>
                <td>Actor</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```